# D3 .transition() not working on circle element onmouseover

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, transition

I am trying to accomplish something fairly simple. I want a line chart with invisible datapoints. When the mouse cursor touches the line these invisible data points should become visible.
I'd like these circles to appear smoothly and thus I have been trying to add a transition to the lines mouseover method.
Additionally if the user hovers over one specific data point a tooltip should appear stating the data points value (e.g. date and value of given metric). Ideally I'd like these circles to start out with radius 0 and when the line is touched the radius should grow to a certain value in a given time

```
datapoints.transition().duration(500).attr("r", 5);
```

When the circle is hovered I want its radius to increase a little more (e.g. in the circles onmouseover method).

```
d3.select(this).transition().duration(500).attr("r", 7);
```

Which did not work.
It is possible however to just set

```
d3.select(this).attr("r", 7);
```

the new radius in the circles onmouseover method but as I said before I want it to be a smooth transition and I have seen way fancier plots out there.

As I couldn't get this to work I tried the next best thing and so I ended up using no transitions at all and I was able to get my chart to look like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3f9fnzqh/3/). Unfortunately a very choppy experience...
I hope that I am missing something very obvious and that somebody can help me out with this.

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for here. Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3f9fnzqh/7/)?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
d3.select(this).transition().duration(500).attr("r", 7);
```

works for me.  The problem here might be that transitioning from a radius of 3 to 7 in 500 milliseconds, isn't all the perceptible.

That said, I've taken some liberty's with your example and [come up with this example](http://jsfiddle.net/3f9fnzqh/8/).  I think it looks pretty dang cool.

```
.on("mouseover", function (d) {
   brandPoints.transition().duration(500)
     .attr("r", 10)
     .each("start", function() {  
       d3.select(this).style("visibility", "visible"); 
   });
   d3.select(this).transition().duration(500).attr("r", 20);

 ...

.on("mouseout", function () {
   brandPoints.transition().duration(500)
     .attr("r", 2)
     .each("end", function() { 
       d3.select(this).style("visibility", "hidden"); 
      });
 ...
```